# Embed YouTube videos are downloading on Android phone instead of playing

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, youtube

I have an AngularJS app that shows an embed Youtube video at the top of the page. The user can click buttons to change the video, which just updates the `ng-src`.

This works fine when viewed on a mobile website with a computer, or when viewed on my friends iPhone, but when I view the mobile site with my Android device it downloads the video file that is currently set to `ng-src` and just shows a blank box where the video should be. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Here is sample code.

HTML

```
<iframe
    ng-src="{{trustSrc(YTSource)}}" controls>
</iframe>
```

Controller

```
$scope.YTSource = $scope.items[0].source;

$scope.changeSource = function(item) {
    $scope.YTSource = item;
};

$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};
```

*Trying to just use `ng-src={{YTSource}}` resulted in a trust error or something, hence why I have to use the `$sce` method.*

So the user can click links to update the `ng-src`, which like I said is working fine on the computer view or on my friends iPhone, but with my Android device it fails to show any embed video (just a blank box), and it downloads the video file (with no prompts). Is there some weird glitch/bug that causes my Android device to do this, rather than show it an embed format?

Comment: Are you using chrome or the stock/vendor browser on your phone?

Comment: @RahatMahbub the chrome browser